# Named parameters in Yesql

Tags: clojure

How can one use named parameters when running queries using Yesql? For instance, given the following query

```
-- name: example
select * from table1 where col1=:value1 and col2=:value2
```

i'd like to use the following code:

```
(defquery q "query.sql")
(q db {:value1 "A" :value2 "B"})
```

Right now, Yesql treats the map as a single positional parameter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of Yesql - 0.4.0 - does not support easily this. The named parameters are only for documentation. You can see them if you do `(doc q)`, but you can't use them to run the query. The author of Yesql has mentioned that [they're planning exactly what you want for Yesql 0.5](https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql/issues/29#issuecomment-56063808).

What I've done in the same situation is to just manually wrap the query into another function:

```
(defn q1 [db {:keys [value1 value2]}] (q db value1 value2))
```

It's a bit cumbersome, but it works.

---

It is possible to do this automatically even without improving Yesql, but... this is going to be a bit of a hack. **You probably do not want to do this.**

We can define a function similar to `apply` that uses the query function's metadata to get the arguments in the right order from the map of named parameters.

```
(defn apply-with-arglist-fn [f arglist & args]
  (let [nargs (butlast args)
        kwargs (last args)]
    (apply f (concat nargs (map #(get kwargs (keyword %))
                                (drop (count nargs) arglist))))))

;; Let's define a macro to make calling this a bit easier.
(defmacro apply-with-arglist [f & args]
  "Applies fn f to the arguments in a map by matching them with f's
  arglist. Works like apply, except that the last parameter should be
  a map of keyword arguments. For example:

     (defn f [a b c] ...)
     (apply-with-arglist f 1 {:b 2 :c 3})

  This is equivalent to calling (f 1 2 3)."
  `(apply-with-arglist-fn ~f (first (:arglists (meta (var ~f)))) ~@args))
```

You can use this to run the query:

```
(apply-with-arglist q db {:value1 "A" :value2 "B"})
```

Really, though, there should be error handling and dealing with corner cases. A better approach would be to see if you can help the Yesql author to get Yesql 0.5 ready.